looking for reference for two elliptic curves with equal formal group
I am looking for a reference.
In this post, @Chris Wurthrich made the following comment:
If the formal group laws (probably upon particular choice of coordinates) of two elliptic curves over any ring of characteristics $0$ are equal, then the curves will be equal and also their equations are equal as
\begin{align*}
   f(X,Y)&=X+Y-a_1XY-a_2X^2Y-a_2XY^2-2a_3X^3Y+\cdots+(-2a_1a_3-2a_4)X^4Y+\cdots\\
   &+(-2a_1^3a_3-2a_1^2a_4-4a_1a_2a_3-2a_2a_4-2a_3^2-3a_6)X^6Y+\cdots
   \end{align*}
That was the comment.
While I don't doubt the computation anyway but I just didn't find a way to justify it. According to his sentences, it seems to me that he mentioned $f(X,Y)$ as the Weierstrass equation of the elliptic curves, but it can be checked that $f(X,Y)$ looks like a 1-dimensional commutative formal group. This is the point where I am confused about the computation. There must be some maths behind the comment.
I hope someone must know it already and there is a reference as well.

Based on the comments you link, I think this is a formula for the formal group law of an elliptic curve, expressed in terms of a coordinate derived from the Weierstrass model (I'm not sure how exactly the coordinate is derived - seems to me there are multiple natural ways), expressed in terms of the coefficients of the Weierstrass equation. So $f$ is not itself the Weierstrass equation but it is derived from the Weierstrass equation.

The point of his reasoning is that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are determined by the first few coefficients, and then $a_4$ is determined by the coefficient of $X^4 Y$ and $a_6$ is determined by the coefficient of $X^6 Y$. However, this requires you to know that the group laws are equal when expressed in this explicit coordinate derived from the Weierstrass model, and not just isomorphic.

Your link to "this post" went to @DanielLitt's comment, so I changed it to point to the main post What is the relation between two abelian varieties that have the same formal group?. I hope that this was all right. I also added a link to @‍ChrisWuthrich's comment. // In response to the obvious comment (that I was about to make!) suggesting you just ask @‍ChrisWuthrich, I point out that you did.

(quickly while on holidays) I got the expansion using sage. https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/formal_group.html. This is an implementation of the description of the formal group in Silverman.

@LSpice, thank you for editing the question into correct way, especially citing the comment

If $A$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ then any formal group law over $A$ is isomorphic to the additive one.  Thus, if $E_0$ and $E_1$ are elliptic curves  over $A$ and you apply any procedure you like to produce associated formal group laws $F_0$ and $F_1$ then $F_0$ and $F_1$ will be isomorphic.  Thus, for the cited statement to have any content, it must refer to equality of FGLs, not isomorphism.  To produce a specific FGL you need to start with a specific Weierstrass equation, not just an abstract elliptic curve.

@NeilStrickland, yes, any $\textit{commutative}$ formal group law over $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra is isomorphic to additive formal group law in any dimension. Anyway, I am assuming the formal group laws are equal, in my question.

@NT2024 Does not the second comment by Will Sawin clarify your confusion? It is never said in the comment you cite that $f(X,Y)$ is the equation of an elliptic curve. It is said that as the formal group law $f(X,Y)$ is of the form indicated, it contains enough information to uniquely recover all coefficients of the equation of the elliptic curve.

@WillSawin, thank you for your nice explanation.
